# Nagios set the host state to CRITICAL only after 2 check

Tags: nagios

I have a nagios server, that is a backup server as well. This server receives auto backup files from over 30 network devices in my network. The network gears send backup files hourly, but not at the same time.
I have a simple script to check if backup file has been created for the last 30 minutes:

```
#! /bin/bash

PROGNAME=`basename $0`
PROGPATH=`echo $0 | sed -e 's,[\\/][^\\/][^\\/]*$,,'`

. $PROGPATH/utils.sh

if [ "$1" = "" ]
 then
  echo -e " Use : $PROGNAME -- Ex : $PROGNAME /etc/hosts \n "
  exit $STATE_UNKNOWN
fi

if [[ -z `find /backupdir/ -name "$1*" -mmin -30 -type f` ]]
 then
  echo "CRITICAL - $1 : backup not working for the last hour" 
  exit $STATE_CRITICAL
 else
  echo "OK : $1 config backup is working  "
  exit $STATE_OK
fi
```

as in 30 minutes there might be some devices that has been backed up timely, is there anyway to set the check service to set to CRITICAL state only after 2 checks in an hour?
I have tried this but seems to not work:

```
 # 'check backup'
 define service {
         hostgroup_name                  ciscos
         service_description             auto backup config check
         check_command                   check_cisco_backup
         use                             generic-service
         normal_check_interval           30
         max_check_attempts              4
         retry_check_interval            4
         notification_interval           60
 }
```

I haven't got enough reputation to add a comment to your reply. Below example is to clarify my question:

```
- router R1 backing up config file to nagios server N1 at the first minute of every hour 
- R2 -> N1 at 31st minute of every hour 
- I want N1 to run 'auto backup config check' service every 30 minute, 
- so at the first time the service run, apparently one of the two routers will be checked as CRITICAL and the other is OK, and the second the service run, the former OK one will be CRITICAL and vice versa
```

Please see if you can help to define the service or modify the script in the most optimal way.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want the check to return green if it has been backed up in the past half hour, yellow if it has not been longer then a half hour and red if it has been longer then an hour?

Comment: normal_check_interval and retry_check_interval are version 2 syntax, btw

Answer (score 0):

Which version of nagios do you use ?
I presume that if you exit with critical state on every check there won't be any escalation. You might exit via an STATE_WARNING and use check escalation
cf : [Nagios check service frequency based on service status](https://serverfault.com/questions/329125/nagios-check-service-frequency-based-on-service-status)